# Will a faster video card improve the performance of the Android emulator?

Tags: android, performance, emulation, gpu

This is a general question. I am trying to create apps for Google TV using the 3.1 Honeycomb OS, which is not yet available on Google TV... Only on Android Tablets. I know that using a device is much faster, but I cannot use it yet.

Therefore, until later this summer I must use the emulator.

The video card on my computer is pretty weak, I do not know what it is at the moment, but I can tell you it was a bargain-bin card. I have 1.5G of DDR RAM, Win XP 32bit, plenty of storage, and almost nothing installed on the computer (I just wiped it this week).

If anyone thinks getting a new video card would improve my performance, please say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting a new video card probably won't help much, AFAIK. I have a notebook with 128MB discrete video RAM and a desktop with 512MB video RAM. Both have the same approximate single-core CPU speed (2.5GHz dual-core vs. 2.66GHz quad-core), and they have comparable Android 3.1 emulator performance.

While graphics are at the heart of the performance issue with the Android 3.1 emulator, it is unclear how much qemu uses hardware graphics acceleration, and the emulator itself has to do all its rendering using software, since it does not have access to the underlying actual hardware.

If you only have, say, $50 to spend, I'd bump up your RAM, so you can allocate 1024MB to the device RAM setting of the AVD. That is known to incrementally improve matters. It is still slow, but not as horrible.

Comment: Thank you for that. I understand what you mean, now, that the emulator doesn't really have access to the physical hardware of my PC, that it has to use its own software to run graphics. That is kind of what I was afraid of.
My PC only had two RAM slots, and so I am now maxed-out on RAM, 512MB came with it, and I just installed 1GB in the empty slot.
Would I be causing harm to switch out the 512MB card to a 1GB card?

Comment: @John Connor: "Would I be causing harm to switch out the 512MB card to a 1GB card?" -- that's a question for your PC manufacturer. I have no way to know.

Comment: +1 for "That is known to incrementally improve matters. It is still slow, but not as horrible". I use 1024 for Device RAM size and it's still slow.

Comment: @CommonsWare Seems this question was answered for old arm emulators. But for x86 emulators will new videocard improves performance? Because i need to try complex animations on an tablet emulator. My PC has 4GB RAM. should i bump up my RAM to 8GB from my current 4GB? .. Which option  is better?

Comment: @manjusg: "But for x86 emulators will new videocard improves performance?" -- probably not much, but turn on GPU emulation for your AVD (hardware options). "My PC has 4GB RAM. should i bump up my RAM to 8GB from my current 4GB? .. Which option is better?" -- I'd go for the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Video Cards and Processor its really important to the emulator speed, i dont know what processor you have, so cant know for sure if only upgrading the Video Card will make a lot of diference but it will definitly be better that the performance you have now.